# Codemodel array

Tags: java, arrays, declaration, sun-codemodel

I use CodeModel to generate Java code.
I expect output like this:

```
public static final String[] COLUMNS = {ID, CODE, NAME};
```

I tried:

```
definedClass.field(JMod.PUBLIC|JMod.STATIC|JMod.FINAL, String[].class, fieldName, JExpr.newArray(codeModel.ref(String.class)));
```

but I do not know how to "add" values to the array.

Answer (score 3):

JExpr.newArray() returns JArray, and JArray.add() can be used to add JExpression instances to the initializer. Assuming ID, CODE, and NAME are, say, JExpression instances for local fields, then:

```
JExpr.newArray(codeModel.ref(String.class)).add(ID).add(CODE).add(NAME)
```

will generate:

```
new String[]{ID, CODE, NAME}
```